# Entity Framework Core define property using a UDF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

New to EF and have the following scenario. I've created a couple of very basic tables/classes to demonstrate what I want to achieve (excuse any potential spelling issues that may be present below, I've just typed this out as an example).

```
   //Model Class
    public class Customer{
        public long Id{ get; private set; }
        public string name{ get; private set; }
        public long status{ get; private set; }
    }

//configuration
public class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Customer");

        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnName("Id")
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(e => e.name)
            .HasColumnName("name")
            .IsRequired();

    }
}

//Tables
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL )


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerJournal](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [RowId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [StatusId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [StatusAlias] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [StatusName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL
)


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerJournal]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomerJournal_Customer] FOREIGN KEY(CustomerId)
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Id])
GO
```

CustomerJournal is a journal of statuses for a customer. I do not have a StatusId on the Customer table, rather I would like to call a UDF to retrieve the latest journal entry.

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[CustomerStatus](
   @CustomerId BIGINT
)
RETURNS BIGINT
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StatusID BIGINT

    SELECT  
        TOP 1
        @StatusID = [StatusId]
    FROM
        [dbo].[CustomerJournal] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        [CustomerId] = @CustomerID
    AND
    ORDER BY
        [RowID] DESC
    
    RETURN @StatusID

END
```

How could I add a property "status" to my configuration class which passes in my Id into this UDF and retrieves it??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can Add a Calculated Column to your Table and use that:

```
public class Customer{
    public long Id{ get; private set; }
    public string name{ get; private set; }
    public long status{ get; private set; }
    // Do this if you are using a DB-First approach
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public long LastJournalEntryId {get;set;}
}

//configuration
public class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Customer");

        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnName("Id")
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(e => e.name)
            .HasColumnName("name")
            .IsRequired();

        // Do this if you are using a Code-First approach
        // "GetLastJournalEntryIdForCustomer" is the name of your UDF
        builder.Property(e => e.LastJournalEntryId)
            .HasComputedColumnSql("GetLastJournalEntryIdForCustomer(Id)");
    }
}
```

Depending on whether you're using Code-First or DB-First you need to create it in the appropriate place first of course.

If you want to map the last Journal Entry to the customer using that column it should work like this:

```
public class Customer{
    public long Id{ get; private set; }
    public string name{ get; private set; }
    public long status{ get; private set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(LastJournalEntry))]
    public long LastJournalEntryId {get;set;}
    public CustomerJournal LastJournalEntry {get;set;}
}
public class CustomerJournal
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public Customer Customer {get;set;}
    public String StatusName {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Are there any ways this could be achieved without a computed column? Just thinking ahead at some other scenarios where it may not make much sense to have a column on the table (Sorry I am new to EF)! I would like to freely call SPs and UDFs from my .NET code but it does not seem to be that easy.

Comment: @Sami.C While I think using a computed column would be best for the scenario you layed out here, you [can actually call UDFs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) from your .NET code, with one restriction: The call must be made inside a LINQ-Statement that gets translated by EF Core.

Comment: Is that something you could tie back to a builder property? Any chance you could show me a sample?

Comment: @Sami.C The article I linked shows a complete example for using UDFs. There is no way to tie them to a Property without creating a Calculated Column unfortunatly, but as I said I think for your scenario a calculated column would be best. You CAN probably use the Calculated column as a foreign key to map an object of the type CustomerJournal as a navigation property.

Comment: @Sami.C I've added an example for mapping the last Journal Entry, that part I haven't tested tho.

Comment: I spent some time looking over the article you sent through and noticed it relies on a .HasDbFunction which does not exist on my EntityTypeBuilder.  How would I replicate "modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(BloggingContext).GetMethod(nameof(ActivePostCountForBlog), new[] { typeof(int) }))
    .HasName("CommentedPostCountForBlog");" with an EntityTypeBuilder. Is this possible?

Comment: @Sami.C not as far as I know. Seeing as DB-Functions exist on the database level it wouldn't make sense to configure them on an entity level.